# N a Nice number

Tags: number-theory

We call a positive integer number N nice if N has an even number of digits, and
has the property that if we insert one multiplication sign in the exact middle of its
digits, then we get that the result of the multiplication is a divisor of N. Identify
all nice numbers. (For example N = 12 is nice since 1 · 2 = 2 divides 12. The
number 1221 is not nice, because 12 · 21 = 252 does not divide 1221.)
Now of course I attempted to solve this . I considered cases like when we have say a six digit number with its third digit as a 2 and its last digit a 2. we split this number in half and multiply we get another even number , so bingo it seems to work for all N that are even . I dont think it works for N ending in prime digits like 3 and 7 
since No factors of the split number forming a product will be a divisor of the prime . that still leaves N ending in the digits 5,8,9 and 0. After thinking this can be done in cases I realized what my intution first told me, that I might be able to express N as sum in terms of 10^k for all k . A(10)^k + B =N 
the product would then be AB right ? this is where im getting stuck any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Why would it work for all evens? It doesn't work for 14. (Or 16, or 18, or 22, or 1242...)

Comment: You are just starting to get some pieces of a valid solution in the last couple of lines of the question. Maybe consider next the equations we can write when one thing divides another.

Comment: Ah so we have to consider A(10^k)+B =mA^nXB for some integer m ?

Comment: You need $AB|(10^kA+B)$ where $A,B<10^k.$

Comment: so what numbers does this generate?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution. But there are some obvious next steps to take, and you may be able to figure out where they go next.

If $N$ has $2k$ digits, where $k\geq 1,$ you can write it as
$$ N = A 10^k + B  \tag1$$
where $A < 10^k$ and $B < 10^k.$
If we don't count numbers like $123$ as a four-digit number (because we could write $0123$), that is, if we don't count leading zeros, then we also have the condition
$A \geq 10^{k-1}.$

Furthermore, we have the condition that $AB$ divides $N,$ that is, there is some integer $m$ such that
$$ A 10^k + B = mAB. \tag2 $$

We can rearrange equation $(2)$ various ways:
\begin{align}
A 10^k &= B(mA - 1) \tag3\\
B &= A(mB - 10^k). \tag4
\end{align}

This shows that $A$ divides $B$ and $B$ divides $A 10^k.$
If we write $B = nA$,  equation $(3)$ implies that

$$10^k = n(mA -1).\tag5$$
This implies that $n$ divides $10^k.$
Assuming $N$ is really a $2k$-digit number in the usual sense, that is,
assuming $A \geq 10^{k-1},$ then $n10^{k-1} \leq nA = B < 10^k$ 
implies $n < 10,$
and together with $n \mid 10^k$ this implies $n$ is $1,$ $2,$ or $5.$

If $N$ is a two-digit number, that is, if $k=1,$ then $n(mA - 1) = 10,$ so $mA - 1$ is $1,$ $2,$ $5,$ or $10,$ that is, 
$mA = 2,$ $mA = 3,$ $mA = 6,$ or $mA = 11,$ respectively.
This means $A$ is either $1,$ $2,$ $3,$ or $6,$ and it should be easy enough to find all two-digit nice numbers by hand. (Hint: $A=6$ doesn't work, but there is at least one solution for each of the other three values of $A.$)

So now let's consider only longer numbers, that is, $k > 1.$
Let's take each possible value of $n$ as a separate case.

Case $n=1$: In this case $B=A,$ so equation $(3)$ implies $mA = 10^k + 1$.
Then $10^k + 1 < 11\cdot 10^{k-1}$
and $10^{k-1} \leq A < 10^k$ implies $1 < m < 11.$
If $10^k + 1$ is prime there is no solution, but if $10^k + 1$ is composite then we're looking for a factor $m$ such that $1 < m \leq 10.$
Clearly $10^k + 1$ is never divisible by $2,$ $3,$ $4,$ $5,$ $6,$ $8,$ $9,$ or $10,$ so if there is any solution at all, then $m = 7$ and we're looking for a number of the form $10^k + 1$ that's divisible by $7,$
and whenever we find one then $A = B = \frac17(10^k + 1).$
You can then show that $AB$ divides $A 10^k + B,$
and with just a little more work you can enumerate all possible nice numbers of this form. (Hint: what's the smallest $k$ such that $10^k + 1$ divisible by $7,$ and what's the smallest $h$ such that $10^h \equiv 1 \pmod7.$)

Case $n=2$: In this case $B=2A,$ so equation $(3)$ implies 
$mA = 5\cdot 10^{k-1} + 1$.
Then $5\cdot 10^{k-1} + 1 < 6\cdot 10^{k-1}$
and $10^{k-1} \leq A < 10^k$ implies $1 < m < 6.$
Clearly $5\cdot10^{k-1} + 1$ is never divisible by $2,$ $4,$ or $5,$ 
but $5\cdot10^{k-1} + 1$ is divisible by $m = 3$ for any positive integer $k.$
So if there is any solution for this case, 
it has $A = \frac13(5\cdot10^{k-1} + 1)$ and $B = \frac23(5\cdot10^{k-1} + 1).$
You can figure out then when $AB$ divides $A 10^k + B,$
and then you can enumerate all nice numbers of this form.
(Try a few examples with actual numbers if it's not clear.)

Case $n=5$: In this case $B=5A,$ so equation $(3)$ implies 
$mA = 2\cdot 10^{k-1} + 1$.
Then $2\cdot 10^{k-1} + 1 < 3\cdot 10^{k-1}$
and $10^{k-1} \leq A < 10^k$ implies $1 < m < 3.$
But $2\cdot10^{k-1} + 1$ is never divisible by $2,$ so there are no solutions in this case.

That's not yet an explicit "function" that "generates" all nice numbers, but if you finish working out each case you should be able to write such a function.
Consider it an "exercise for the reader."
You can even generate the nice numbers in order of increasing size if you want.

Comment: this is good but it doesnt seem to create a function that generates Nice numbers. Unless you just put in various integers for n , m and k ? Guess this problem from the outset is not very Nice at all!